# PhpUnit does not identify TypeError with string numbers and Abstract Class

Tags: phpunit

With the following class

```
declare(strict_types=1);

abstract class IntValueObject
{
    public function __construct(protected int $value)
    {
    }
}
```

and the test

```
declare(strict_types=1);

final class IntValueObjectTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testWithNotValidValue(): void
    {
        $value = '1';
        $this->expectException(\TypeError::class);
        $this->getMockForAbstractClass(IntValueObject::class, [$value]);
    }
}
```

return

> 1. Api\Tests\Shared\Domain\ValueObject\IntValueObjectTest::testWithNotValidValue
>    Failed asserting that exception of type "TypeError" is thrown.

If I change $value from '1' to 'foo' if it passes the test.

We use PHP 8, and in production, if the value '1' is passed it would give TypeError, why doesn't this happen in the test?

Thanks in advance.

---

ORIGIN OF THE "PROBLEM"

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81258

POSSIBLE SOLUTION

```
declare(strict_types=1);

final class IntValueObjectTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testWithNotValidValue(): void
    {
        $value = '1';
        $this->expectException(\TypeError::class);
        new class($value) extends IntValueObject {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Please formulate an answer to your question  - instead of editing the question for solutions (it is generally fine to answer your own questions on stackoverflow). You can then (after some time) accept your own answer, too, which will mark the question as answered. (please note that in my answer I pointed to declare(strict_types=0) and hinted the mock/instantiation as cause of it (that is related to reflection) as well as outlining the solution by creating a class of its own to mock the abstract class.) Cheers!

Comment: Edit the question by adding "abstract class" so that you can help other people in the same situation.
I prefer to wait before validating the possible solution, in case there is a better alternative.

Comment: Well mocking with `$mock = new class(...) extends Abstract {...};` can be viable. I'd say (and this is why I answered it firsthand) that for stable code, the test-suite of that code should provide concrete mocks within the test-suite. And it's not that Phpunit would/n't verify strict-type declarations, it's that PHP does this and if you use a mocking library which does not assert this nor makes use of PHP for it, there is no TypeError to expect at the end of the day. Alternatively it is possible to use static analysis on the code to cover these things without writing unit-tests.

Comment: I extended my answer with more insights so it is easier to gather a better understanding, incl. the component that you may see as the culprit. At the end of the day it highly depends which checks you need, then test for them accordingly. E.g. PHP will always throw the TypeError when `declare(strict_types=1)` so it should normally not be necessary to test for that on the abstract class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One explanation I can imagine is that during the test, `IntValueObject::__construct('1')` is called from code that is not using `declare(strict_types=1);` and therefore the string `'1'` is being coerced to integer `1`. No **TypeError** is thrown in that case (but it would for string `'foo'` - as you describe the behaviour in your question).

### The Cause

The cause is using a generated mock:

```
<?php declare (strict_types = 1);

...

        $this->expectException(\TypeError::class);
        $this->getMockForAbstractClass(IntValueObject::class, [$value]);

...
```

To not have a TypeError in this situation is likely unexpected to you as you have scalar strict types but still see the type-coercion of the string `'1'` to integer `1` for the constructors' first parameter.

#### The Mismatch

However the **TypeError** *is* only thrown when the code calling `IntValueObject::__construct(int $value)` has `declare(strict_types=1)`.

While the test-code *has* `declare(strict_types=1)` it *must not* be that code where the constructor method is called - as no **TypeError** is thrown.

#### For Real

Behind the scenes `$this->getMockForAbstractClass(...);` uses an [***Instantiator*** from the Doctrine project](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-instantiator/en/1.4/index.html) which is making use of [*PHP reflection (meta-programming)*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). As those methods are all internal code, `declare(strict_types=1)` is not effective and there is no *TypeError* anymore.

Compare with the following code-example:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class Foo {
    public function __construct(int $integer) {
        $this->integer = $integer;
    }
}

try {
    $foo = new Foo('1');
} catch (TypeError $e) {
} finally {
    assert(isset($e), 'TypeError was thrown');
    assert(!isset($foo), '$foo is unset');
}

$foo = (new ReflectionClass(Foo::class))->newInstance('1');
var_dump($foo);
```

When executed with assertions enabled, the output is the following:

```
object(Foo)#3 (1) {
  ["integer"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Within the try-block, the TypeError is thrown with `new` as you expect it.

But afterwards when instantiating with PHP reflection it is not.

*(see as well https://3v4l.org/aZTJl)*

### The Remedy

Add a class to your test-suite that *is* really mocking the abstract base class and place it next to the test of it so you can easily use it:

```
<?hpp declare(strict_types=1);

class IntValueObjectMock extends IntValueObject
{...}
```

Then use **IntValueObjectMock** in your test:

```
        $value = '1';
        $this->expectException(\TypeError::class);
        new IntValueObjectMock($value);
```

Alternatively use [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) when extending it is straight forward:

```
        $value = '1';
        $this->expectException(\TypeError::class);
        new class($value) extends IntValueObject {};
```

Or apply type-checks on the constructor method your own, either with PHP reflection or [run static code-analysis](https://psalm.dev) which has the benefit that it can detect such issues already without instantiating - so no additional test-code is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer hakre.

As I put in the post, 'declare (strict_types = 1)' is included in the test class and in the abstract class.

If the test is done on a class that extends from the abstract, as you describe, it works.

But I would like to be able to test the abstract class and verify the TypeError.

Comment: Then writing the mock in PHP code should work. As you've tried it and as you said it works, I'd say that is an answer then. Extending from an abstract class is normally the only way to test it for real. Esp. as constructors are implementation details. I couldn't figure out the actual reason why it does not throw per `$this->getMockForAbstractClass`, the templates in Phpunit have strict types, too. Perhaps it is the way how the mock class is instantiated?